# Android BroadcastReceiver unable to receive Screen_On and Screen_Off broadcasts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get my BroadcastReceiver, created inside of a service, to receive Screen_On and Screen_Off events. It is not working, here is what I am trying right now.

```
//OnCreate Method for the service
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myBroadcast = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter screenOn_Off = new IntentFilter();
    screenOn_Off.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    screenOn_Off.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(myBroadcast, screenOn_Off);
}

//Inner class for the broadcast receiver, also in the service.
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Broadcast received", "Broadcast received");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
            startTimers();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
            screenLocked();
        }
    }
};

//Declaration of receiver in manifest.
        <receiver
        android:name="com.bla.bla.bla$MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        </receiver>
```

I purposely did not include the intent filters for the screen_on and off because I read that those must be declared programmatically, including them made not difference.

Comment: I just placed a log inside each if condition. fired broadcast via adb and works fine for me.! :s

Comment: you code working properly. check whether Service is running or not.

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu I must be misunderstanding when these broadcasts get launched. I press the lock button on my phone, and I expect the screen_off broadcast, and I don't get it. So I guess I don't know what broadcast I am supposed to be looking for.

Comment: You are right. Thats the way it works.. i went one step further and placed break point inside the if conditions and checked by locking the screen it indeed received the broadcast. :s